# JQuery is not working for click event on local machine,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JQuery is not working for click event on local machine, but correctly working on JSfiddle please see this linke[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neelabhsingh/xr8getb7/). In following code, I am trying to hide and show the div's rest part. Following code is working perfectly on jsfiddle, but on local machine click is giving no response. Please tell me where I am wrong..

```
<html>
      <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>  
        $("#grid_content").on("click", ".toggle", function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();    // Prevent window following #hash / jump
          var more = $(this).text() === "Show More";
          $(this).text(more ? "Show Less" : "Show More").prev(".restPart").slideToggle();
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
            .bucket {
              width: 290px;
              float: left;
              margin: 0 0 48px 20px;
              border: 1px solid #262626;
              background: lightgray;

            }
            .restPart{
              overflow:auto;
              display:none; /* hide initially */
            }

      </style>
     </head>

     </body>
        <section id="grid_content">

          <div class="bucket">
            <p>Visible part....</p>
            <div class="restPart">
              <p>Content...</p>
            </div> 
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Show More</a> 
          </div>

          <div class="bucket">
            <p>Visible part....</p>
            <div class="restPart">
              <p>Content...</p>
            </div> 
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Show More</a> 
          </div>

        </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code inside:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //code here
});
```

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you.

And it works in jsfiddle because `onload` is selected so it automatically wraps your code inside `$(whindow).load(function(){})`:

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.
>   Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run
>   once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

[**Reference**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the DOM to render. Therefore wrap your code in jQuery block for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#grid_content").on("click", ".toggle", function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();    // Prevent window following #hash / jump
          var more = $(this).text() === "Show More";
          $(this).text(more ? "Show Less" : "Show More").prev(".restPart").slideToggle();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `script` tags should be at the bottom of the body, below all your HTML. I believe JSFiddle does this automatically.

Basically: JQuery is not finding your ID selector because it doesn't exist yet.

CSS goes at the top. JavaScript goes at the bottom.

At the point that script tag runs, the DOM looks like this:

```
<html>
      <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>  
        $("#grid_content").on("click", ".toggle", function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();    // Prevent window following #hash / jump
          var more = $(this).text() === "Show More";
          $(this).text(more ? "Show Less" : "Show More").prev(".restPart").slideToggle();
        });
    </script>
```

There's no element with ID `grid_content`, the page hasn't rendered it yet. A script is run immediately when the browser hits it, so you always want to put JavaScript at the bottom of your body.

It's worth noting that the other answers mentioning `document.ready` are also valid, it's just good practice to always put your JavaScript at the bottom of your body, if the browser is busy running your JavaScript then it's not rendering the page - what if your JavaScript is heavy and takes a few seconds to run?

Comment: Inside body or outside body.

Comment: Inside the body, after everything else.

Comment: As I said in my answer, JQuery could not find your ID Selector because it hadn't been created yet. I'll edit my answer ^